# Swift - How to use FireStore Authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am struggling with a problem for a while now.

I am using FireStore Database in my Swift project.

Here is my sample fragment of code:

```
     db.collection("XXXX").whereField("XXXX", isEqualTo: XXX).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
// SUCCESFULL 

    }
```

The thing is that, in my database, currently I do not have any Rules implemented. So it is not secure. I want to implement to my swift project so that I can modify the rules on my database.

I do not understand how to enable Authentication for my swift project.

In the Nature of my project, there is no user authentication needed by the users who is willing to use the application.

How can I implement authentication just before the database query in the code, so that the rules on my database satisfies.

The authentication must be independent on the users since there is no authentication mechanism exists in my swift projects since I do no need the users to authenticate in the app.

Can you share a simple authentication code or something so that I can use in my project ?

I tried to read the docs on google but they are all related to User Authentication Methods such Facebook, Email/Password, SMS .. etc

Thank you in Advance Guys

Comment: If I understand, it seems like you want a user to authenticate just before a read? That's going to get awfully cumbersome for the user. Why not just have basic [email/pw authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth) which is pretty easily implemented. If nothing else, use [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth) so you at least have some control over what users can or cannot do (like erase your database!).

Comment: Hi Jay, Thank you for your comment. I did not understand how Anonymous Authentication help securing the database ? There is no key exchange or secret builtin key or such a thing. Anyone who has the URL can implement Anonymous login on their behalf to gain access to database. Is that true ?

Comment: That is not correct. Just because someone has the URL to a database doesn't mean they can access it. The Firebase Rules control read/write access as well an enforcing the format of what data is written. I was suggesting anonymous not as a final solution but to limit what an anonymous user can do. Say only allow them to read/write to a Public message board. Any other access would then require them to register with an email & password and the UID they were originally assigned would remain with that user. Ultimately, some kind of authentication would be best to prevent abuse & security issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also think to create a Generic User and embed the email/password combination of that single user in the source code for authentication in the application. 

In this way, all the users that launch app will authenticate by the email/password credentials that is stated in the source code.

What do you think about that method ? It seems more secure than Anonymous to me, what about you ?

Comment: I think best practice is to *never* embed any kind of authentication within your code. If this is a *read only* type of app, like a weather app where users can only observe (read) data, you can easily restrict writing to none via the rules and allow reading for all and eliminate authentication. However, if users are allowed to write data, authentication would be recommended to control the data being written and to prevent someone from spamming your database (like a DOS attack) as that would cost you $$ or wiping your database completely.

Comment: Hi Jay, I think you are right.

Comment: Hi Jay, I think you are right. But the thing is that I can not ask user any login information in my application. I am trying to figure out the most secure way that, a user can read/write to database without experiencing any login step while using the application. 

I need to find out implement security without making the user to login while using the application. Thats why I thought may be a static login credentials can be implemented. 

May be firebase is not suitable for my use case :( I may need to impelement PHP-WS and use a server-side old faction mechanism with MySQL database. 
:(

Comment: I don't think another database solution would help as if you are allowing *anyone* to read/write to your database then anyone could write as much data to the server as they want in whatever format they like - opening yourself to a lot of issues; a nefarious person could write hundreds of gigabytes of the wrong type of data which would cost you a fortune in server fees and cause your apps to potentially crash. Maybe just re-thinking your authentication strategy would be in order? Just a thought.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179853/discussion-between-yagiz-ozen-and-jay).